# Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) …?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have some problems with my XML code. It does not shows any error on editor. But while cleaning project it shows the following error

*Error:(285) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)*

This is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ash432.tapmatch.game_main"
    android:background="#a7f666">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sec"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/res"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/time1"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:editable="false"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/_00_1"
        android:id="@+id/mili"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/_00"
        android:id="@+id/sec"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/score"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:editable="false"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/b4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/b4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/res" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb4"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/b8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/res" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b3"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb7" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b2"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb6" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b8"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b4"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb8" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b9"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b5" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b11"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b9"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b7"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb11" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b10"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb10"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b9"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b6" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b12"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b10"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b8"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb12" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b13"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b9"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b9"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb13" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b14"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b16"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b10"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb14" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b15"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b13"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b11"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb15" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/b16"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b13"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b12"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="buttonClickb16" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/res"
        android:text="@string/restart1"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:background="#01fef2"
        android:onClick="buttonClickres" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="10sp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/colon2"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mili"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/b2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/score1"
        android:id="@+id/s1"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mili"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/b7" />
</>
```

Comment: Is this </> causing the problem??

Comment: yes.. replace </> with </RelativeLayout>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your XML, change

```
</>
```

to

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

That is the correct syntax for the closing tag of your `RelativeLayout` https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp

Comment: It's not correct the syntax for an XML closing tag.